# multithread streamming with tweepy

Tags: multithreading, twitter, web-scraping, tweepy

Is there a way to implement a multi-thread streamming in twitter using tweepy? 
Currently I am using the following code:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TWITTER_APP_KEY, TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

stream_listener = tweepy.StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(track=["token"], async=True)
stream.filter(track=settings.TRACK_TERMS)
```